# Zero divisors in annihilator of modules

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I faced a theorem

> Let $R$ be a noetherian local ring, $M$ a finitely generated module of finite projective dimension. 
>   Then if the annihilator of $M$ is not trivial, then it contains a nonzero zero divisor in $R$.

Or more precisely, in this form.

[image]

This is a part of Vasconcelos' paper [Ideals Generated by R-Sequences](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82227314.pdf), he referred paper of Auslander and Buchsbaum [Homological dimension in local ring](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-02/S0002-9947-1957-0086822-7/S0002-9947-1957-0086822-7.pdf).  But there is no Proporsition 6.2 in the paper referred.

My question is, how to prove this proposition?

Comment: The correct reference is [2, Proposition 6.2].

Comment: See Theorem 19.8 of "Matsumura".